# unorder list make an hovering background instead of hover the link(text)

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I dont know how to explain for this, i have a menu bar with href link but how can make it like when hovering the item box it's like equally hover the link?

```css
ul li a:link{color:#0F0F0F;text-decoration:none;}
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
 }
 
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
  background: #fff;
  color:#2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom:8px solid black;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #929292;
  background-color:#000000;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;  
}

ul li ul li 
{ 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-bottom:solid 1px white;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li ul li:hover { background: #000;}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
    <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
      <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
      <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
      <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
      <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
      <li ><A href="https://www.google.com.my/">apple</A></li>
 </ul>
```

expected result : menu bar background color will be changed when hover outside area of hyperlink and also allow to click from outside the hyperlink.

Comment: try to this code ul li:hover {
    color: #929292;
    background-color: #000000;
}

Comment: ul li:hover {
  color: #929292;
  background-color:#000000;
}

Comment: Not only background color change, how to make it also clickable as a link?

Comment: See my edited answer, that should solve the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?
Instead of the link text, you want the whole button to change color?

```css
ul li a:link{color:#0F0F0F;text-decoration:none;}
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
 }
 
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #fff;
  color:#2A0851;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom:8px solid black;
  border-left:1px solid grey;
}

ul li:hover {
  color: #929292;
  background-color:#000000;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;  
}

a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

ul li ul li 
{ 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-bottom:solid 1px white;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li ul li:hover { background: #000;}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

a { display: block; padding: 10px 20px; }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="alert('click!');" >apple</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Exactly! thank you @DDan

Comment: I'm glad to help, please accept the answer! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @DDan, may i know can to make it work on hyperlink too ? i mean not only hover the button but it can be click too from the outside area ..

Comment: Ok, I edited the css, needed to move the 'padding' from `li` to `a` elements.

Comment: Now it is alerting 'click' message, so you can see that it works on the area not only on text.

Comment: Thanks again @DDan, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

> Modify your css style as below:

```
ul li{
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 10px 20px;
border-bottom: 8px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid grey;
cursor: pointer;
background: #2A0851;
}
ul li a{
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
color: #fff;
}
```